# No items returned from public activities request

Tags: google-plus

For most profiles, I can easily retrieve public activities. However, I have found one profile that for some reason does not return activities even though I can see them posted on their G+ page.  The profile is: 111558147839170177177 and I am making the call below.  Note the empty items array.

[https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/111558147839170177177/activities/public?key=[yourkey]](https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/111558147839170177177/activities/public?key=%5byourkey%5d)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the page is age restricted. If you view the page in an incognito window, the posts are not shown.